# Is there a difference between "slanted eyes" and "almond eyes"?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, difference

I see many people saying that there is no difference and that **almond eyes**
it is a non-offensive alternative to **slanted eyes**, but I also see many saying that the two are totally different from each other.

I'm sorry if are errors, my English isn't good.

Comment: There is nothing inherently wrong about slant**ed** eyes or rounded eyes. It is other terms that look like slant**ed** that are considered to be an insult: Slant, slant-eye, slant-eyed, google dictionary.

Comment: @Lambie.  I completely disagree that a minor change to an expression widely accepted as an insult will reliably avoid strong overtones of that insult.  The insult in all versions of this word come from the context of their use. If I substitute “slanted” in sentences in which the other versions were used to communicate a racial slur, the slur will remain.

Comment: @OrbitalAussie You would not make it on the make-up or cat circuit. Just using slanted eyes is not a racial slur in and of itself. There are plenty of non-Asians with slanted yes.

Comment: It is possible to talk about the shape of people’s eyes without causing offense, but it is difficult to do so when using words that immediately suggest an insult merely because that’s how they have been used in the past. English speakers associate certain words with racial insults, for example, and so they are best avoided. For this reason saying “almond eyes” might help remove any suggestion of insult when (for example) sincerely admiring a friends eyes. But context is so important here - even “almond eyes” might be intended to be, or taken to be, an insult.